# Read inconsistently formatted csv file into Pandas Dataframe (blocks with headline and repeating column headers)

Tags: python, csv, pandas, malformed

I have a CSV file which basically looks like the following (I shortened it to a minimal example showing the structure):

```
ID1#First_Name
TIME_BIN,COUNT,AVG
09:00-12:00,100,50
15:00-18:00,24,14
21:00-23:00,69,47
ID2#Second_Name
TIME_BIN,COUNT,AVG
09:00-12:00,36,5
15:00-18:00,74,68
21:00-23:00,22,76
ID3#Third_Name
TIME_BIN,COUNT,AVG
09:00-12:00,15,10
15:00-18:00,77,36
21:00-23:00,55,18
```

As one can see, the data is separated into multiple blocks. Each block has a headline (e.g. `ID1#First_Name`) which contains two peaces of information (`IDx` and `x_Name`), separated by `#`.

Each headline is followed by the column headers (`TIME_BIN, COUNT, AVG`) which stay the same for all blocks.

Then follow some lines of data which belong to the column headers (e.g. `TIME_BIN=09:00-12:00`, `COUNT=100`, `AVG=50`).

I would like to parse this file into a Pandas dataframe which would look like the following:

```
ID  Name        TIME_BIN     COUNT  AVG
ID1 First_Name  09:00-12:00  100    50
ID1 First_Name  15:00-18:00  24     14
ID1 First_Name  21:00-23:00  69     47
ID2 Second_Name 09:00-12:00  36     5
ID2 Second_Name 15:00-18:00  74     68
ID2 Second_Name 21:00-23:00  22     76
ID3 Third_Name  09:00-12:00  15     10
ID3 Third_Name  15:00-18:00  77     36
ID3 Third_Name  21:00-23:00  55     18
```

This means that the headline may not be skipped but has to be split by the `#` and then linked to the data from the block it belongs to. Besides, the column headers are only needed once since they do not change later on.

Somehow I managed to achieve my goal with the following code. However, the approach looks kind of overcomplicated and not robust to me and I am sure that there are better ways to do this. Any suggestions are welcome!

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO (<- Python 3, for Python 2 use from StringIO import StringIO)

pathToFile = 'mydata.txt'

# read the textfile into a StringIO object and skip the repeating column header rows
s = StringIO()
with open(pathToFile) as file:
    for line in file:
        if not line.startswith('TIME_BIN'):
            s.write(line)

# reset buffer to the beginning of the StringIO object
s.seek(0)

# create new dataframe with desired column names
df = pd.read_csv(s, names=['TIME_BIN', 'COUNT', 'AVG'])

# split the headline string which is currently found in the TIME_BIN column and insert both parts as new dataframe columns.
# the headline is identified by its start which is 'ID'
df['ID'] = df[df.TIME_BIN.str.startswith('ID')].TIME_BIN.str.split('#').str.get(0)
df['Name'] = df[df.TIME_BIN.str.startswith('ID')].TIME_BIN.str.split('#').str.get(1)

# fill the NaN values in the ID and Name columns by propagating the last valid observation
df['ID'] = df['ID'].fillna(method='ffill')
df['Name'] = df['Name'].fillna(method='ffill')

# remove all rows where TIME_BIN starts with 'ID'
df['TIME_BIN'] = df['TIME_BIN'].drop(df[df.TIME_BIN.str.startswith('ID')].index)
df = df.dropna(subset=['TIME_BIN'])

# reorder columns to bring ID and Name to the front
cols = list(df)
cols.insert(0, cols.pop(cols.index('Name')))
cols.insert(0, cols.pop(cols.index('ID')))
df = df.ix[:, cols]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO
import sys
pathToFile = 'mydata.txt'
f = open(pathToFile)
s = StringIO()
cur_ID = None
for ln in f:
    if not ln.strip():
            continue
    if ln.startswith('ID'):
            cur_ID = ln.replace('\n',',',1).replace('#',',',1)
            continue
    if ln.startswith('TIME'):
            continue
    if cur_ID is None:
            print 'NO ID found'
            sys.exit(1)
    s.write(cur_ID + ln)
s.seek(0)
# create new dataframe with desired column names
df = pd.read_csv(s, names=['ID','Name','TIME_BIN', 'COUNT', 'AVG'])
```

Comment: Excellent and still very fast on large files! I would just remove either line 7 (`s.write('ID,Name,TIME_BIN,COUNT,AVG\n'`) or the `names=['ID','Name','TIME_BIN','COUNT','AVG']` in the last line - otherwise you get the column headers twice.